# Compatibility issues with react-native and react? (moved packages / dependencies)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I recently updatet my project to the following:

> └── react-native@0.45.1
>   └── react@16.0.0-alpha.12

This is my package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-native": "^0.45.1",
    "react-native-button": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.12.2",
    "react-native-exception-handler": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-orientation": "^1.17.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^4.8.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.2",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.5.4"
  },
```

My project worked fine when it was empty, but after importing Button from `react-native-button`; the madness begun. These are the error messages I recieved:

```
Warning: PropTypes has been moved to a separate package. Accessing React.PropTypes is no longer supported and will be removed completely in React 16. Use the prop-types package on npm instead.
Warning: React.createClass is no longer supported. Use a plain JavaScript class instead. If you're not yet ready to migrate, create-react-class is available on npm as a drop-in replacement.
```

I will start using these new packages, but the errors are from within the `TouchableOpacity` component and some components it uses:

`AnimatedImplementation` -> `ViewStylePropTypes` -> `LayoutPropTypes` 
`Animated` -> `Image.android` -> `View`

The same happens when I extract the code and make the necessary changes as expected:

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    View,

    Text,
    TouchableOpacity,
    ViewPropTypes,
    StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import coalesceNonElementChildren from '../../lib/coalesceNonElementChildren'
import { AppStyle } from '../../lib/appStyles'

const systemButtonOpacity = 0.2;

export default class AppButton extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        ...TouchableOpacity.propTypes,
        allowFontScaling: PropTypes.allowFontScaling,
        containerStyle: ViewPropTypes.style,
        wrapperBorderStyle: ViewPropTypes.style,
        wrapperStyle: ViewPropTypes.style,
        disabled: PropTypes.bool,
        style: PropTypes.style,
        styleDisabled: PropTypes.style,
    };

    render() {
        let touchableProps = {
            activeOpacity: this._computeActiveOpacity(),
        };
        if (!this.props.disabled) {
            touchableProps.onPress = this.props.onPress;
            touchableProps.onPressIn = this.props.onPressIn;
            touchableProps.onPressOut = this.props.onPressOut;
            touchableProps.onLongPress = this.props.onLongPress;
        }

        return (
            <View style={this.props.wrapperBorderStyle ? this.props.wrapperBorderStyle : styles.wrapperBorder}>
                <View style={this.props.wrapperStyle ? this.props.wrapperStyle : styles.wrapper}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        {...touchableProps}
                        testID={this.props.testID}
                        style={this.props.containerStyle}
                        accessibilityTraits="button"
                        accessibilityComponentType="button">
                        {this._renderGroupedChildren()}
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
    _renderGroupedChildren() {
        let { disabled } = this.props;
        let style = [
            styles.text,
            disabled ? styles.disabledText : null,
            this.props.style,
            disabled ? this.props.styleDisabled : null,
        ];

        let children = coalesceNonElementChildren(this.props.children, (children, index) => {
            return (
                <Text key={index} style={style} allowFontScaling={this.props.allowFontScaling}>
                    {children}
                </Text>
            );
        });

        switch (children.length) {
            case 0:
                return null;
            case 1:
                return children[0];
            default:
                return <View style={styles.group}>{children}</View>;
        }
    }

    _computeActiveOpacity() {
        if (this.props.disabled) {
            return 1;
        }
        return this.props.activeOpacity ?
            this.props.activeOpacity :
            systemButtonOpacity;
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    wrapperBorder: {
        borderRadius: 7,
        backgroundColor: AppStyle.controlBorderColor,
        paddingBottom: 5,
        margin: 10,
        marginLeft: 30,
        marginRight: 30,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },

    wrapper: {
        borderRadius: 7,
        backgroundColor: AppStyle.controlBackgroundColor,
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
    },

    text: {
        color: AppStyle.controlTextColor,
        fontSize: 17,
        fontWeight: '500',
        textAlign: 'center',
    },
    disabledText: {
        color: AppStyle.disabledControlTextColor,
    },

    group: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
});
```

I don't understand what happened because i've used react@16.0.0-alpha.12 before with success. What am I missing? Should I update or downgrade something in order for my project to work?

Comment: This happens because the dependency components that you might be using still dont have that change. for now you should downgrade you React version and ensure that the components that you use follow the current procedures

Comment: I'm trying to keep up with the latest version, I guess all these versions make my head spin a little. I'll try

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I downgraded my react version back to version 16.0.0-alpha-6, but my react-native version (0.45.1) complains about `peer dep missing: react@16.0.0-alpha.12, required by react-native@0.45.1` so react-native itself is indicating that it needs this version.

Comment: I have no idea how to fix this but I also get these warnings when I setup a new project using `react-native init HelloWorld`. It's probably an issue with the react package itself.

Comment: Yes, that's my observation as well. I recently used [react-native-git-upgrade](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-git-upgrade) to install a template and it installs [Expo](https://expo.io/) as a wrapper. Now I'm back at RN 0.44.3 and everything is working. Altough no custom modules support which basically is no help at all